# TFS WIQL report upload on report server

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, tfs, wiql

Which UI control should be used to display data using C# TFS APIs (WIQL) so it can be uploaded on report server or can produce .rdl file?

Comment: A little bit too broad. Can you be more specific and include code that is in question?

Comment: There is none directly. Through excel you can convert a query to a report. But that still isn't an Rd file... I don't think there is an easy way to do just that.

Comment: OK. Then, how should I create TFS complex report (without MDX, SSRS) which can be deployed on report server?

Comment: I am creating C# application which is fetching all data from TFS and displaying it on Report Viewer control. How should I deploy this report viewer (rdlc) file on SharePoint so it display TFS data and charts?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a web service in .net that serves the data that you want and consume that easily in Reporting Services...